# Update a Field on DE if Subscriber already received an Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

How can i implement Ampscript once email was sent on a Subscriber? Say field from DE named Status from No to Yes once email was sent to subscriber is this possible?
Any example, thanks in advance.

Comment: Once email is gone, you cannot do anything about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a `%%_messagecontext%%` [personalization string](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) and use `UpsertDE(1,2,3,4,5,6)` function

**paramters:**

1   -> Name of data extension from which to update specified row

2   -> Number of filter columns to insert or update

3   -> Column name used to build the WHERE clause

4   -> Value used to build the WHERE clause

5   -> Column name used to build the INSERT clause

6   -> Value used to build the INSERT clause

```
%%[
if _messagecontext == "SEND" then
  UpsertDE("SendDE",1,"SubscriberKey",_SubscriberKey,"status","yes")
else
  UpsertDE("SendDE",1,"SubscriberKey",_SubscriberKey,"status","no")
endif
]%%
```

you have put this sample of code in your email and then send it to your subscribers

Comment: you are welcome, Please upvote the answer so others can also check it. @MarkDacillo

Answer (score 0):

You could add the function [UpdateDE](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/updatede/#UpdateDE) in the Template email; in this way after the email sending, AMPscript will update one or more Data Extension fields (Status (Y/N) and Date Sent).